# How to write a query that retrives only object where association is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models :

```
 Product
 has_many :variants

 Variant
 has_many :stocks
 belongs_to :product

 Stock
 belongs_to :variant
```

I need to retrive the **Variant** where **Stock** is not empty

I tried this way but this does not work as expected... as it is empty it is not nil...

```
 @product.variants.includes(:stocks).where.not(stocks: nil)
```

Comment: Do you mean `@product.variants.joins(:stocks)`? `joins` will create an `INNER JOIN` so any `Variant` that does not have at least one `Stock` will not be included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

More simpler version of what you did....
using [Has Many association reference](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

and in my Product Controller

```
def show
  @product_size_options = []    
  @product.variants.map do |var| 
     ##this will make sure that only persisted stocks comes out
      if var.stock_ids.size > 0
        @product_size_options  << var
      end
    end
 end
```

The above code can also be written in one line =>

```
@product.variants.map { |var| var if var.stock_ids.size > 0 }.compact.flatten
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I did find  a working solution in a different way:

In my Variant model

```
def has_stock
   self.stocks.empty? ? false : true
end
```

and in my Product Controller

```
def show
  @product_size_options = []    
  @product.variants.map do |var| 
      if var.has_stock == true
        @product_size_options  << var
      end
    end
 end
```